# ANOVA test on dataset

Tags: dataset, probability-or-statistics

I have a dataset with 3 groups and two variables. I want to do ANOVA test on the three groups for each variable. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
Needs["ANOVA`"]
ds = Dataset[{
<|"group" -> "1", "var" -> "var1", "value" -> 6.035053959`|>,
<|"group" -> "1", "var" -> "var1", "value" -> 6.193979765`|>,
<|"group" -> "1", "var" -> "var1", "value" -> Missing["UnknownData"]|>,
<|"group" -> "1", "var" -> "var1", "value" -> 3.3745613910000003`|>,
<|"group" -> "2", "var" -> "var1", "value" -> Missing["UnknownData"]|>,
<|"group" -> "2", "var" -> "var1", "value" -> 0.001071983`|>,
<|"group" -> "2", "var" -> "var1", "value" -> 0.00197519`|>,
<|"group" -> "2", "var" -> "var1", "value" -> 0.000850834`|>,
<|"group" -> "3", "var" -> "var1", "value" -> 0.001295309`|>,
<|"group" -> "3", "var" -> "var1", "value" -> 0.000994449`|>,
<|"group" -> "3", "var" -> "var1", "value" -> 0.003818416`|>,
<|"group" -> "3", "var" -> "var1", "value" -> 0.002378116`|>,
<|"group" -> "1", "var" -> "var2", "value" -> Missing["UnknownData"]|>,
<|"group" -> "1", "var" -> "var2", "value" -> 0.00677702`|>,
<|"group" -> "1", "var" -> "var2", "value" -> 0.001844996`|>,
<|"group" -> "1", "var" -> "var2", "value" -> 0.005386635`|>,
<|"group" -> "2", "var" -> "var2", "value" -> 1.320257649`|>,
<|"group" -> "2", "var" -> "var2", "value" -> 1.090243962`|>,
<|"group" -> "2", "var" -> "var2", "value" -> 1.6674887180000002`|>,
<|"group" -> "2", "var" -> "var2", "value" -> 1.88535474`|>,
<|"group" -> "3", "var" -> "var2", "value" -> 0.446011094`|>,
<|"group" -> "3", "var" -> "var2", "value" -> 0.46027675799999995`|>,
<|"group" -> "3", "var" -> "var2", "value" -> Missing["UnknownData"]|>,
<|"group" -> "3", "var" -> "var2", "value" -> 0.344685377`|>}]
```

I've tried this simple code, but it doesn't work:

```
ds[GroupBy[#var &], ANOVA["value"]] /@ {"var1", "var2"}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are a few complications to handle. From the code you proposed, it seems to me that you want to run one-way ANOVA on the two subsets obtained by grouping the data according to the value of the `"var"` key in the full dataset.

However, to carry out one-way analysis, `ANOVA` accepts input as a list of lists of *two elements*, not three, as you can see from [its documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ANOVA/ref/ANOVA.html). In addition to that, my attempts indicate that `ANOVA` will also not handle the `Missing` data points, so they have to be removed.

Here is a sequence of steps I would suggest:

**1)** Remove missing data that can't be handled by ANOVA:

```
DeleteMissing[ds, 1, 1]
```

[image: removed missing data placeholders]

**2)** Split the original dataset into two datasets according to the value of the "var" column *)

```
GroupBy[#"var" &][%]
```

[image: dataset of datasets, one per value of var]

**3)** Extract only the *first and third* columns from each subsets, because the second column containing the "var" value is now the same for all data points in each subset and therefore superfluous:

```
%[All, #[[All, {1, 3}]] &]
```

[image: middle column removed]

**4)** Remove the data labels from the associations to prep the data for ANOVA:

```
%[All, All, Values]
```

[image: data labels removed]

**5)** Apply one-way ANOVA to each dataset:

```
Needs["ANOVA`"]
%[All, ANOVA]
```

[image: ANOVA results in the dataset format]

The above is shown as a dataset, which truncates some of the results. A more traditional result formatting can be obtained with `Normal`:

```
% // Normal
```

[image: ANOVA results in traditional format]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! Your suggestion works for the most part, but the `DeleteMissing[ds,1,1]` does not work as you wrote it. I get an error message saying the the DeleteMissing only works with 1 or 2 arguments. However `DeleteMissing[ds,1]` does not do anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AudunB That's weird. On second thought, a better choice of arguments would have been `DeleteMissing[ds, 1, Infinity]`, but either this last one, or the original one I posted both work as intended on my end (I've just reloaded your dataset and tried again). `DeleteMissing[ds, 1]` wouldn't work because it only looks for `Missing` values at the first level, and yours are deeper than that. What version of MMA are you using? Could you try restarting the kernel just to see whether some leftover definitions are getting in the way?

Comment: I'm on version 10.0.1. I tried to restart but still get the error "too many arguments". `DeleteMissing[ds,Infinity]` sort of works, but it only removes the `Missing["UnknownData"]` and replaces it with `KeyAbsent`.

Comment: That is really weird. Out of curiosity, this (http://i.imgur.com/GiqRb8V.png) is what I see when I type `DeleteMissing` in a notebook and then press CTRL+Shift+K to pull up the syntax templates. The last template is clearly the one I am using. I wonder whether you see it as well.

Comment: I see this [http://i.imgur.com/5MvZv48.png]. I clearly is missing the last option that you have. But when using Wolfram Programming Cloud I get the same options as you do. Guess I can use the programming cloud for that particular step.